# How to use exported module variable inside the module where it was declared

Tags: typescript

What is the proper way to refer to an exported module level variable inside a function that is located in the typescript module where the variable was declared? I have noticed that both ways work, but only when the full path to the variable is specified does hover debugging work in Visual Studio.

```
module MyModule {
  export let var1: string = "Hello";

  function test() {
    let a: string = var1; //This works fine, but VS hover debugging does not.
    let b: string = MyModule.var1; //This works, but is more coding.
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the TypeScript Analyzer requires the full path to the namespace level variable, that's what I decided to use. (MyModule.var1)